# animating a circular opening door

Tags: animation, modifiers

I'm trying to create a circular opening door:
[image]

When I try and Apply the transformations to the curve I get the follower error:
`Rotation/Location can't apply to a 2D curve: Object "Spiral.001", Curve "Spiral.001", aborting`

What I want to do is add an array modifier then set an object constraint at the origin.  But when I do that, because the transforms aren't all zeroed the curve goes everywhere when I set an object offset. I already know to use Follow Path.

I'm using a nurbs path.

Comment: can u please add a link how the animation should look like? thx

Comment: This looks a little bit like a camera-iris mechanism. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing some videos and playing with the scene I was able to solve my problem.  What I did was I went to `Add Object Constraints > Follow Path`
I then selected the path in my **Target**.
After which you tick[image][image]

Sorry for lacking a video. I'll edit and add it to my answer soon.